# Asterisk Playback with no answer on dahdi channel?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, dahdi

Here is my sample dialplan

```
        exten => _X.,1,Progress()
        exten => _X.,n,Playback(welcome,noanswer)
        exten => _X.,n,Hangup()
```

When I tried to call through dhadi channel. I am getting the below logs in asterisk console.

```
-- Accepting call from '9042394773' to '33468550' on channel 0/8, span 1
-- Executing [33468550@test:1] Progress("DAHDI/i1/9042394773-8", "") in new stack
-- Executing [33468550@test:2] Playback("DAHDI/i1/9042394773-8", "welcome,noanswer") in new stack
-- <DAHDI/i1/9042394773-8> Playing 'welcome.slin' (language 'en')
-- Executing [33468550@test:3] Hangup("DAHDI/i1/9042394773-8", "") in new stack
-- Hungup 'DAHDI/i1/9042394773-8'
```

But the welcome voice is not audio able.. How do I play weclome voice before atten the call??? Whether I have to change any configuration in asterisk????

Am using asterisk 13.5.

Comment: What TYPE of dahdi channel you have?

Comment: @arheops E1 PRI lines.. dahdi version is 2.10. ISDN PRI line

Comment: Check your card support early media(likely yes), check other side support early media(likely not)

Answer (score 0):

I found this example where a Wait(1) is used between Progress and Playback.
Maybe you can give it a try.

```
exten => 500,1,Progress()
exten => 500,n,Wait(1)
exten => 500,n,Playback(WeAreClosedGoAway,noanswer)
exten => 500,n,Hangup()
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the difference of adding the wait() inbetween of both the lines?

Comment: I sincerely don't know the reason but you can reference this [Asterisk official documentation](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Early+Media+and+the+Progress+Application)